# How do I highlight CVS changes in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, highlight, cvs

I'm using emacs with cvs and have cvs mode enabled.   I'd like to get line-by-line highlighting of changes from the latest version in CVS.   I've seen this done in intellij where there is a green indication for lines added and another indication for lines modified and a third symbol for lines deleted.

Is there a cvs highlighting mode for emacs to show changes from the latest version of cvs?  I'm not looking for a `cvs diff` type functionality that would open in a new buffer, but something that would indicate in my current buffer what lines have been modified.

In the following image there is a blue rectangle on the left side in what Intellij calls the "gutter" to indicate that the code is different than what is in source control.

[image: intellij example]
<sub>(source: [jetbrains.com](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/screenshots/60/actions.gif))</sub>

I'm looking for similar functionality in emacs.

Comment: please s/cvs/vcs so we get an answer for any git/bzr/hg/svn...

Answer (score 3):

You can now check out [diff-hl](https://github.com/dgutov/diff-hl), which provides highlighting on the left window fringe.

So far I've tested it only on a few modern DVCSes, but if you're still using CVS, and it doesn't work as well, please file an issue.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another answer that doesn't do what you want either, but may be useful.

```
C-x v g
```

runs the command `vc-annotate`.

That'll pop up a new buffer (I know, you didn't want one), but it'll have all the lines marked with who touched them when.  And, bonus, they're color coded with a heatmap (red is most recent, blue is least), for easy identification of recent changes.

Of course the built-in version of vc-annotate doesn't scroll the buffer appropriately, so you'll want this advice:

```
(defadvice vc-annotate (around vc-annotate-and-scroll)
  "scroll buffer to view current line in the annotated buffer"
  (let ((pos (count-lines (point-min) (point))))
    ad-do-it
    (let ((orig-window (selected-window))
          (window (other-window-for-scrolling)))
      (select-window window)
      (goto-line pos)
      (select-window orig-window))))

(ad-activate 'vc-annotate)
```

Comment: It has been usefull at least to me :)

Answer (score 1):

You want `vc-diff`, which is on `C-x v =` by default. This gives you raw diff output in a temp buffer. The buffer uses diff-mode, which has a few neat tricks ... for example, you can use `C-c C-e` to apply the diff as a patch to another file. Use `describe-mode` (`C-h m` by default) in the diff buffer to find the other tricks.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you'd like [Ediff](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/emacs/ediff.html#SEC_Top), which appears to do exactly what you want.

Comment: Not exactly what I am looking for.  I want a minor mode so it can always be on when editing code.  I also want to compare directly against CVS without getting a second local copy of the original version.

Comment: How does IntelliJ handle this? It seems like what you're asking is awfully expensive...